# python - geo binning - averaging values within a geo boundary

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation

With data like below, - captures measurements at various close locations

```
Lat Long    val
35.611053   139.628525  -72.82
35.61105336 139.6285236 -78.04
35.61105373 139.6285223 -72.99
35.61105409 139.6285209 -69.04
35.61105445 139.6285195 -65.4
35.61105482 139.6285182 -66.68
35.61105518 139.6285168 -65.82
35.61105555 139.6285155 -64.47
35.61105591 139.6285141 -71.26
35.61105627 139.6285127 -68.36
35.61105664 139.6285114 -74.48
35.611057   139.62851   -74.27
35.61105736 139.62851   -77.97
35.61105773 139.62851   -68.66
35.61105809 139.62851   -70.21
35.61105845 139.62851   -76.05
35.61105882 139.62851   -88.83
35.61105918 139.62851   -73.17
35.61105955 139.62851   -67.63
35.61105991 139.62851   -71.85
35.61106027 139.62851   -77.42
35.61106064 139.62851   -71.08
35.611061   139.62851   -79.27
```

Need to perform binning operation on this data - that is to get mean of all the values in `val` every 0.1x0.1 meters. One approach could be to find the edges ( like NW, SW, NE & SE) and divide it into a set of 0.1x0.1 meter grids and lookup values within each grid and compute average and attribute to the lat/long at the center of the grid so that we have results like below.

```
Lat Long    Mean_val    Sample_count
```

While the proposed approach may be naive, wanted also know if there could be an approach based on `pandas`

Comment: I'm familiar with 2D histogramming but not familiar with Lat and Long. What are max and min in each column? Also: can we assume the heart to be flat in each square, right?

Comment: Yes, for this purpose we can consider earth to be flat :) the NE corner would be defined by `(max Lat, min Long)` where as the SE corner would be `(min Lat, max Long)`

Comment: I see, but let's generalize: we are going to do a two dimensional histogram. `x` is going to be `Lat` and `y` is going to be `Long`. We will make bins from `min(x)` to `max(x)` and idem for `y`. Probably it is not needed, but I don't want to give you a bugged code: what are the values of `min(x), min(y), max(x), max(y)`? This is where out two dimensional grid will be.

Comment: in geo-coordinates, `x` would be `Long` and `y` would be `Lat`. So `NW` corner would be `(min(x),max(y)`. `NE` corner would be `max(x), max(y)`. `SE` corner would be `min(x), min(y)`. `SW` corner would be `max(x), min(y)`.

Comment: the question real is how you calcuate your avg value I think. suppose you only have one point in that area, value -77 at (35.6 139.6). how it's heat spread out? I mean there must be a function. like gauss distribution or something else.

Comment: in this context, the average value is `(sum of all values in the grid)/(num of samples in the grid)` , if there are no samples it can be `NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simple solution to average data by 0.1 m * 0.1 m area

To do that you must convert your latitude,longitude coordinate into an x,y coordinate.

Here I use the `utm` module:

```
x,y,_,_ = utm.from_latlon(latitude, longitude)
```

After that you can create a new column which represent your x,y coordinate in decimeter :

```
def apply_fun (raw):
    x,y,_,_ = utm.from_latlon(raw['Lat'],raw['Long']) 
    return str(np.round(x*10))+"|"+str(np.round(y*10))
```

Then add it to your dataframe  :

```
x = df.apply(lambda row : apply_fun(row),axis=1)
df.insert(3,'Group',x)
```

and you apply the groupby function :

```
gdf = df.groupby(['Group']).agg({"Lat":["mean"],"Long":["mean","count"],"val":["mean"]})
gdf = gdf.reset_index().drop(columns=['Group'],level=0)
gdf.columns = [' '.join(col) for col in gdf.columns]
```

And we are done ! :)

## Generalization of the previous solution

To group data by k1 meters * k2 meters area, just modify this function :

```
def apply_fun (raw):
    x,y,_,_ = utm.from_latlon(raw['Lat'],raw['Long']) 
    return str(np.round(x/k1))+"|"+str(np.round(y/k2))
```

## Criticism of the previous solution

As I indicated previously to solve this problem, we have to convert the lat, long  into x, y coordinates.

In the previous solution I converted the lat,long to utm coordinates. The utm system is a cartographic projection which divides the earth into 120 areas : 60 north and 60 south. So when we do :

```
x,y,area_number,NS = utm.from_latlon(raw['Lat'],raw['Long'])
```

`(x,y)` is our position in the `(area_number,NS)` area. We can conclude that our solution work if and only if our sensors are in the same UTM area.

We can also do this conversion using the ECEF conversions which directly converts lat,long into x, y coordinates. I do not know the precision of these methods and as we are asked for precision to the tenth of a meter I prefer to choose the utm convertion which look more accurate.

If you want to use the ECEF method done like this :

```
import pyproj
def gps_to_ecef_pyproj(lat, lon, alt):
    ecef = pyproj.Proj(proj='geocent', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')
    lla = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')
    x, y, z = pyproj.transform(lla, ecef, lon, lat, alt, radians=False)

    return x, y, z

x,y,z = gps_to_ecef_pyproj(raw['Lat'],raw['Long'],0)
```

(I take the code from here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230160/converting-wgs84-to-ecef-in-python)

Comment: could you provide reference for the decimeter conversion. And also generalizing it a bit more how could it be done any `n meters` by `n meters` grid  - for example 0.44*0.44 meters or 1.21*1.21 meters

Comment: also is there a way to get the number of samples that have been averaged by `df.groupby(['Group']).mean()` for group.

Comment: 0.1 meters = 1 decimeters = 10 centimeters. To get the number of sample averaged you can do len(df) - len(df.groupBy(['Group']).mean()). If that answer helped you please consider validate the answer ^^

Comment: the answer helps. may be I did not explains the `sample_count` part clearly. as in the OP, need the number of samples averaged for each row in the grouped data to get `Lat Long    val    Sample_count`

Comment: Oh ok I go eddit that. I didnt see this part

Comment: This answer is generally incorrect without more geographic context about the data. from the [documentation](https://github.com/Turbo87/utm) of `utm` notice that  the function `utm.from_latlon` returns a 4-tuple: `(EASTING, NORTHING, ZONE NUMBER, ZONE LETTER)`. If the data spans mutiple [utm zones](http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm) then it would be erroneous to use their (x,y) in this way.

Comment: Yes of course I go edit it and i will be more accurate in my answer.  I will try to explain to show some others convertion methods and to talk about their précision